# want to display consecutive Friday date for Saturday and Sunday. and from Monday is use current date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am taking date from server and need to display on html page .
date will change every day . but on saturday sunday will show friday date .

again from next monday it will regular date please help`
i am taking span for display .
getServerTime is for requesting server date.

HTML:

```
<span id="currentdate"></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
];
var allmonth = new Array(12);
allmonth[0] = "january";
allmonth[1] = "february";
allmonth[2] = "march";
allmonth[3] = "april";
allmonth[4] = "may";
allmonth[5] = "june";
allmonth[6] = "july";
allmonth[7] = "august";
allmonth[8] = "september";
allmonth[9] = "october";
allmonth[10] = "november";
allmonth[11] = "december";

function getServerTime() {
    return $.ajax({
        async: false
    }).getResponseHeader('Date');
}
var st = getServerTime();
var date = new Date(st);
//alert(date+"this is server date");
var day = weekday[date.getDay()];
var currentdate = date.getDate();
var currentmonth = allmonth[date.getMonth()];
var currentyear = date.getFullYear();
var fulldate = currentdate + "-" + currentmonth + "-" + currentyear;
var fridayday = "";


if (day == 'Monday' || day == 'Tuesday' || day == 'Thursday' ||
    day == 'Wednesday') {
    $("#currentdate").html(fulldate);

    alert("this is working day");
} else if (day == "Friday") {
    fridayday = fulldate;
    alert("this is friday");
    alert(fridayday + "fridayday date inside if");
    $("#currentdate").html(fulldate);

} else if (day == 'Saturday' || day == 'Sunday') {
    $("#currentdate").html(fridayday);
    alert("this is not a working day");
}


alert(fridayday + "fridayday date out side if");
```

Comment: 1. `async: false` is a big no no. Don't use. _Ever_. It shouldn't even exist. 2. Don't reinvent the wheel and use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/). It's got all sorted out for you.

Comment: guide me with example of movement of momentjs

Comment: Uh well.... they wrote [an excellent documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) for that

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood through reading your question, you want to display on days Friday, Saturday and Sunday the same thing. So why dont you implement Saturday and Sunday in your `else if` statement ?

i.e.:

```
 else if (day == "Friday" || day == "Saturday" || day == "Sunday") {
    fridayday = fulldate;
    alert("this is " + day);
    alert(fridayday + "fridayday date inside if");
    $("#currentdate").html(fulldate);

}
```